# Deep questions in number theory not accessible by combinatorial results

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, big-list, arithmetic-geometry

Number theory and arithmetic geometry were invented to solve many questions about properties of numbers. What are the some of the foundational results or estimates that are accessible to powerful tools in arithmetic geometry but so far inaccessible to any improvement by combinatorial constructions?

Comment: Can you give an example of some result that's not accessible by combinatorics in any area? I mean in principle every application of a higher-powered tool can be unwinded into elementary steps, and all sorts of symbol pushing and diagram chasing is combinatorial in some way.

Comment: I would guess error estimates in arithmetic geometry.